# How to use a global variable in ASP.net without using it as a static variable.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there any method were we can define the global variables in c# which shouldn't be static, as static variable values gets changed in the fly.

Comment: Static variables do not get changed on the fly. The problem is different - a static variable is shared among all requests to the page. Instead, use `Session` state.

Comment: I want to give one scenario in this context, i want to define a global variable which can be used by all the methods in that class. but asp.net only allows to declare is as static, whereas static variables can be changed if the same class is used by other users. So currently I have to use hidden label  to store the global values? Is there any other way for this?

Comment: When you say all the methods in the class, you mean all the methods in the page? Just create a non-static instance, and it will be available to all methods for the duration of the request. `private MyClass _myInstance = new MyClass();`

Comment: I don't think that this is off topic. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: I also think this should be reopen. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Any way I got my answers. Thanks John Saunders and Șhȇkhaṝ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a Seesion variable for that.

```
 Session["Key"]=value;
```

Create a property get and set and use in you code. As session is different for different user it will work fine.

### Edit 1

```
 public string yourProp {
     get {return Session["Key"].ToString()} 
     set {Session["Key"]=value}
 }
```

Also you need to initialize or put some value on page load `!ispostback` so that there is no `null reference error.`

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should try to get out of the habit of thinking of these things as global variables. However, instance members of the class behave the same was as "global variables", but only during the span of each request:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    private SqlConnection _conn;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        _conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, _conn)){
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, on each request, you'll get a new instance of SqlConnection - it will not have the value that it did on the previous request.